# Pegar último login do usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Em meu projeto me surgiu essa regra de negócio.

Preciso pegar a ultima vez que o usuário se logou no sistema. Então seria algo para que eu conseguisse pegar o dia e a hora do último login.

Já tenho a coluna criada no banco de dados chamada `UltimoLogin` que é um `DateTime`.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Código do *Controller*

## AutenticacaoController

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(String Login, String Senha)
    {
        //verificando login pelo usuario do banco de dados ...
        Usuario login = db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Login == Login && x.Senha == Senha).FirstOrDefault();

        if (login != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Nome.ToString(), false);
            Session.Add(".PermissionCookie", login.Perfil);
            Session.Add("UsuarioID", login.UsuarioID);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // página padrão para todos os usuários
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");           
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim, quando você for fazer o login do usuário sete a propriedade `UltimoLogin` para `DateTime.Now` e salve as modificações. Se esse `db` é uma instancia de um `DbContext` do Entity Framework ficaria assim

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(String Login, String Senha)
{
    //verificando login pelo usuario do banco de dados ...
    Usuario login = db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Login == Login && x.Senha == Senha).FirstOrDefault();
    if (login != null)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Nome.ToString(), false);
        Session.Add(".PermissionCookie", login.Perfil);
        Session.Add("UsuarioID", login.UsuarioID);
        login.UltimoLogin = DateTime.Now;
        db.Entry<Usuario>(login).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //pagina padrao para todos os usuarios...
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

E basicamente quando você precisar desse dado é so você pegar o valor daquela coluna. Se, como eu imaginei, você estiver usando o Entity Framework, ele já vai botar o valor pra você na propriedade `UltimoLogin` do objeto `Usuario`. A enumeração `EntityState` fica no namespace `System.Data.Entity`